# How to return data with swr in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, swr

I try to display data and I use swr data fetching with react and here is the code :

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from "axios";
const fetcherFunc = (...args) => {
  return axios(...args).then((res) => console.log(res.data));
};
function MyComponent() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/",
    fetcherFunc
  );
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}
export default MyComponent;
```

The problem is that it's stuck in loading and the data won't get updated and is undefined also the console log of data in fetcher appears to work .

How to fetch data with swr in react and display fetched data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to return `res.data` from `fetcherFunc` instead of `console.log`-ing data.

Also, just use `url` as the name of the argument for the `fetcherFunc` and pass that url to `axios.get` (don't use `...url` spread operator on url). Take look at [How To Use Axios for Data Fetching](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) (passing the url, method, payload, etc).

Function for fetching the data should look like:

```
const fetcherFunc = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);
```

As for the `useSWR` hook, use it like this:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/", fetcherFunc);
```